# Resourceful Routes helpers _path and _url dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to redirect user to `show_city_url` or `show_city_path` but i get an exception that they are both undefined.In the city controller i have three actions show,like, and dislike. `unlike_city_path` and `like_city_path` works but `show_city_path` doesnt.Also when i put this in all_cities action `redirect_to :controller=>"city",:action=>"show"` works.What am i doing wrong?Thank you.

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController  

    def all-cities
       redirect_to show_city_url
    end  

   end
```

In the Routes

```
     resources :city do
     member do
     post :like
     post :dislike
     get  :show
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your comments:

```
resources :cities, :controller => 'city' do
  collection do
    get :show, :as => :show
  end

  member do
    post :like
    post :dislike
  end
end
```

now you can call `show_cities_url` and you'll land in the show action of your CityController.

PS: Following the Rails' convention makes your life easier ;)

RoR Guide: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: what's the name of your controller that shows/lists the cities?

Comment: ok it will naturally look for a "CitiesController" (plural) so two solutions: 1) rename it to plural 2) specify the controller in your routes.rb like `resources :cities, :controller => 'city' do`

Comment: Thank you alot sled!I did option 2.It worked.But i am unable to force to show_cities_url though,is there anyway to do that?

Comment: why do you want to do that? `cities_url` goes to the index (lists all cities) `city_url(@city_id)` goes to the show page

Comment: my set up is a little different i am showing all cities in in show page ,that is why.I didnt follow rails convention.city_url(@city)takes me to index page also